# Determining whether the given statement is true or not .

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

$Problem$
Is above equality right ?

$A\cap(B-C)$= ($A\cap B$)-($A\cap C$)

$Attempt$

> > Statement 1

$A\cap(B-C)$ = 
($A\cap B$) $\cap$ ( ($A\cap C'$)

> > Statement 2

($A\cap B$)-($A\cap C$)
= ($A\cap B$) $\cap$ ( ($A\cap C$)'

How to proceed after this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your work on the second statement, you apparently are aware that

$$A -B = A \cap B'$$

but if you apply that to the first statement, you immediately get

$$A \cap B \cap C'$$

Now, the second statement indeed becomes

$$( A \cap B) \cap (A \cap C)'$$

You can proceed with:

$$=A \cap B \cap (A' \cup C')$$

$$=(A \cap B \cap A') \cup (A \cap B \cap C')$$

$$=\emptyset \cup (A \cap B \cap C')$$

$$=A \cap B \cap C'$$